# Reading properties values from Resource and from System Variables in Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to configure my Spring 4 application to be able to read properties values using the `@Value` annotation.
I need to be able to read values from `.properties` files as well as from `system properties`.

For reading from `.properties` file I am using `@Value("${my.propery.name}")` syntax along with `@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")`.

For reading from system properties I am using the `@Value("#{systemProperties['myVariableName']}")` syntax.

In my `ApplicationConfig.java` class, which is the main application configuration file I have both:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

and:

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
return new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

When both Configurers are specified, I experience an issue in which sometimes the values are resolved and sometimes not (and I get a `Could not resolve placeholder` exception).

When only `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is configured, I am able to read only from .properties file.

When only `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is configured, I am able to read only from system properties.

What is the best configuration for reading from both resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I managed to resolve the issue by registering only the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean and specifying a the `.properties` file path as a `Resource` in it:

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
 PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc= new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
 ppc.setSearchSystemEnvironment(true);
 final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("my.properties");
 ppc.setLocation(resource);
 return ppc;
}
```